# CSS validator throws parsing error with CSS animation media query

Tags: css, validation, animation

this is interesting as I can't really find anything on the web really to do with why my code throws a parsing error. The code below shows i have a media query that basically changes a few elements and their properties.

When i validate this code it throws a parsing error because of the swim animation, when i remove this animation and re-validate the code it passes without any problems.

Can this be fixed or just something that can be ignored :) ?

```
@media (max-width: 1325px) {
  #chapter-one-background, #chapter-two-background, #chapter-three-background {
    height: 450px; }

  #sound-button {
    width: 21px; }

  .buttonCenter {
    padding: 50px 0px 20px 0px;}

  html {
    font-size: 1em; }

  h1 {
    font-size: 3em; }

  h2 {
    font-size: 2.027em; }

  h3 {
    font-size: 1.199em; }

  h4 {
    font-size: 1em; }

  .button-wrapper {
    padding-top: 50px; }
    .button-wrapper .buttons img {
      max-width: 90%; }

  .exchange-list img {
    max-width: 20%; }
  .exchange-list .list-float-right {
    width: 230px; }

  .article-center {
    width: 300px; }

  .article-info {
    width: 350px; }
    .article-info img:last-child {
      width: 100%; }

  #cloud-background {
    padding: 2% 2% 4% 2%; }

  .article-center-video {
    width: 400px; }
    .article-center-video .article-info-video {
      width: 400px; }

  .eyes-container {
    margin-top: 280px; }

  .sun {
    top: -300px; }

  #cowhead1 {
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px; }
    #cowhead1 img {
      width: 90px; }

  #hands-behind-left {
    height: 663px; }

  #chapter-four-background-left {
    height: 663px; }

  #cowhead2 {
    top: 100px;
    left: 180px; }
    #cowhead2 img {
      width: 90px; }

  #info2-chapter3 {
    padding-top: 80px; }

  #exchange-chapter3 {
    padding-top: 90px;
    left: 15%; }

  #info1-chapter3 {
    padding-top: 110px; }

  #chapter-four-background-right {
    width: 250px; }

  @keyframes swim {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
      -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
      -o-transform: translateX(0px);
      transform: translateX(0px); }

    50% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(500px);
      -moz-transform: translateX(500px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(500px);
      -o-transform: translateX(500px);
      transform: translateX(500px); }

    100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(1000px);
      -moz-transform: translateX(1000px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(1000px);
      -o-transform: translateX(1000px);
      transform: translateX(1000px); } } }
```

Comment: Validating code that use browser prefix will more or less always throw errors since that is basically invalid, and those you can ignore. What error code do you get?

Comment: Yeah, the prefix is not a problem that I'm aware of but i get a parsing error when the above code is ran within the CSS validator. If i remove the Swim keyframe towards the bottom of the code it will validate perfectly.

I'm guessing its something to do with keyframes within media queries.

Comment: Yes, correct, move the _keyframes_ rules outside the _media query_

Comment: The problem is these animations need to be within the media query as the animation needs to be resized on mobile devices ? Im guessing then this error just needs to be ignored ?

Comment: No, you should put the rules that has the actual `animation` property inside the _media query_ and keep the _keframes_ rules outside

Comment: sorry what i mean is that the keyframes need to be within the media query as the pixels for translateX property is reduced for mobile phones.

Comment: No, they don't .. will post an answer for you in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the classes that has the actual `animation` property inside the `@media` query and keep the `@keframes` rules outside

Done like that you still control the actual animation with the media query and it will pass the validator without error

```
@media (max-width: 1325px) {
  .class-that-animate {
    animation: swim 2s;
  }
}

@keyframes swim {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
      -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
      -o-transform: translateX(0px);
      transform: translateX(0px); 
    }
    50% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(500px);
      -moz-transform: translateX(500px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(500px);
      -o-transform: translateX(500px);
      transform: translateX(500px); 
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(1000px);
      -moz-transform: translateX(1000px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(1000px);
      -o-transform: translateX(1000px);
      transform: translateX(1000px); 
    } 
}
```

---

For different `translateX` values on different device size, you make 2 rules and 2 keyframes (here without the prefixed values to make it easy to read)

```
@media (max-width: 1325px) {
  .class-that-animate {
    animation: swim 2s;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .class-that-animate {
    animation: swim-mobile 2s;
  }
}

@keyframes swim {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0px); 
    }
    50% {
      transform: translateX(500px); 
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(1000px); 
    } 
}

@keyframes swim-mobile {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0px); 
    }
    50% {
      transform: translateX(250px); 
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(500px); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes this works but if you wanted to change the pixels for translateX on mobile then the keyframes would surely have to sit inside the media query ?

Comment: @Mayo No, you need 2 _keyframes_ rules (which you will need either way), one for each media query ..... will update my answer in a sec

Comment: @Mayo Updated my answer

Comment: Oh yeah of course!! haha silly me, thats super awesome though thank you! as i didn't know this before hand :) thank you so much mate!